# Subfigures one below the other

Tags: subfloats

I have three figures of width=4.0in and height=2.0in. There is a legend "south outside" of the figures. Anyways, I want to have all three figures on one page. If it's not possible, since they are too big, two figures on one page and the other on the next. However, when I simply include the graphics (code is provided at the end), then there is only one figure per page. And the rest of the page gets filled with text - which I don't want. I was thinking, maybe the subfigures environment would work? - But can subfigures be one below the other? Or are they always parallel?

```
\begin{figure}[t]
\centering
\input{power1}
\caption{Input power.}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[t]
\centering
\input{power2}
\caption{Output power}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[t]
\centering
\input{average}
\caption{Average}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: No they are not always parallel. Example witb subfloats http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/229456/124842

Comment: There are limits on how many figures can go on a page, and how much space they can use. First, use [tbp] instead of [t] (in fact, never use just one option).  Second, increase \topfraction, \bottomfraction and reduce \textfraction.  See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat/39020?s=1|0.0000#39020 for defaults.

Comment: @JohnKormylo If the idea is to have them on one page, probably changing the fractions is irrelevant. Best to make it one figure with subfigures and let it be a float page. That sounds like what the OP wants.

Comment: @cft - OTOH, if they won't fit on one page (due to the legend?) then subfigure will push into the bottom margin.  [p] will put as many as will fit on one page, but wastes space.

Answer (score 1):

Experiments with `[p!t]` placed all three on the same page, but only if they were inserted at the top of the page.  If one or two will fit on the current page, then they will be and the rest will follow ASAP.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
\afterpage{% delay insertion to the top of the next page
\begin{figure}[p!t]
\centering
\rule{4in}{2in}
\caption{Input power.}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[p!t]
\centering
\rule{4in}{2in}
\caption{Output power}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[p!t]
\centering
\rule{4in}{2in}
\caption{Average}
\end{figure}%
}% end of \afterpage
\lipsum[3-8]
\end{document}
```

[image: full page]